# How to find a variable address under Linux

Tags: linux

apologize I can not post the code because I don't have a code :(
Problem :
1) I've an bin file (obtained from source.c)
2) the bin file above runs without problem in Linux OS
3) I know that in this bin file there is a variable(the name is var1)
4) I need to implement a new bin file which is able to found the var1 address in the first bin file only using  with the name of variable.

I've tryed to generete the assembly file from source.c so  to found some start point, but ... :(

Comment: `objdump -t binfile` will print the address of a global external variable. Would that be useful for you?

Comment: Thanks, but var 1 is not external global and is not present in your dump.Thanks in any case!

Comment: If it is a local automatic variable, it will be located in the stack, and that would have a different address each time the program is run... that would complicate the problem.

Comment: I know...this is the reason because I don't have a code to post. I tried to explore \proc\<pid>\ directory...without success

Comment: If you read `/proc/PID/maps` you'll find a line with `[stack]`. That will be the stack of your (main thread) process. Maybe you can locate your variable as a fixed offset from the beginning of that segment.